# Выстроить по горизонтали иконки с текстом так, чтобы текст их не обтекал

Tags: css, flexbox

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы текст в 2-3 строки находился на одном уровне справа от иконки, не обтекая ее. Проблема в том, что в тексте (li) есть еще span, и если задаю тексту flex, то он разбивает этот блок на 3 части, а не на 2, как мне надо. Иконку ставила с помощью :before. [image: текст обтекает иконку]

```html
Ваш код
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: @AndreyFedorov: зачем? Тренируйте телепатию.

Comment: не могу разобраться как добавить сюда код (

Comment: @SvetlanaKachalina картинку смогли вставить, а код не можете? Помог вам слегка.